# Vimrc mappings in a mac keybord

Tags: linux, vim, keyboard, mapping

I am trying to map a key with the command `set filetype=…` which could be perl or html etc.
Problem: I am using a Mac keyboard and all the Fx keys seem not to respond except 2 which I have already mapped and need them.
E.g. doing `map <F14>:set filetype=perl<CR>` or F13 etc not only does nothing it seems to do something weird to the console.
How can I map these without affecting other existing mappings?

**Note:**
To be clear: I am using vim remotely doing ssh. My local keyboard is from Mac

Comment: `:set filetype=perl` is a workaround, ask about the problem, not about your failed attempts at solving that problem.

Comment: @romainl:You have a point. In some cases the syntax "breaks" especially in big files. When I "scroll" down if a file is mixed e.g. html + perl then only html is properly highlighted.I am looking for a fast way to view perl or what ever when I want and return back to the original version

Comment: I don't remember perl and html mixing natively. Is this script using `__DATA__` to separate the perl and html? Or is this some kind of perl template language? Should you be using templates? Can you show us an example of the code (redacted of course) so we can see it and test it out ourselves?

Answer (score 1):

nmap  l
nmap  h
This answers your question but I don't advise you to go that way.

The first problem you'll encounter is that all of your cmdsomething mappings are going to fail in the terminal.

The second is that MacVim doesn't support multiple modifiers: you won't be able to have CtrlShiftb, for example. Well, it will work but the Shift part will be ignored so you will be limited very quicly.

The third problem will be that you'll fail to commit Vim's commands to memory. The day you'll ssh into a server and use Vim there you'll be lost.

So yeah, you CAN do that but (I think that) you SHOULDN'T.

Comment: So what other option do I to avoid typing `:set filetype=…`

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that there should be space between  and :set filetype=perl...

If that was just a typo, then try this interactively,
:map *"press control-v and then press F14 key"* :set filetype=perl

BTW, the apple keyboard (on windows) I use does not have F14 key, and I do not remember seeing any function key beyond F12 on any Macbook, maybe this is something new...

Also, type ":help function-key" in you vim and if it shows something like this, then you cannot do this.

*function keys 1 to 12      *function_key* *function-key**

Comment: I have `<f1>` to `<f15>` on my board. Here is a [picture](http://irwinhkwan.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/fn-key-mac.jpg) I found showing it.